# How to change Default login button in googleplus in ios?

Tags: ios

I am planning to implement Google plus for login in my app? The SDK has a default login button. But I don't want to use that button instead of that I have to "Sign in" with button which i have designed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should call the sign in method on a action of your `googlePlusSignInButton`

So the code should be:

```
-(void) setGooglePlusButtons {

    self.googlePlusSignInButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];


    UIImage *backgroundButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bt_search_cancel.png"];

    googlePlusSignInButton_.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                               0.0f,
                                               backgroundButtonImage.size.width,
                                               backgroundButtonImage.size.height);

    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    googlePlusSignInButton_.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,
                                                                 -1.0f);

    [googlePlusSignInButton_ setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"UI_BUTTONS_LOGIN", @"")
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [googlePlusSignInButton_ setBackgroundImage:backgroundButtonImage
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [googlePlusSignInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signInGoogle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```